# Print progress using arcpy for blocking function

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, clip, progress

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 and through python I am calling arcpy's Clip function to clip a HUGE road network. This takes almost 2 days.

Is there a way I can see the progress?

Clip is a blocking call so I am not sure how to use SetProgressor.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can use setProgressor for this example because it needs some type of interval and since Clip occurs all at once, nothing for setProgressor to go by, unless you are looking for 0 and 1.

I think threading might work for you as it allows multiple processes to occur simultaneously. I personally like thenewboston's yt channel over a lot of documentation (although I will reference guides afterwards). Here's a link to his threading tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WaXK8G1hb_Q

In addition to the question, you stated it takes ~2 days. Are you clipping the entire network as opposed to just the roads that go over the boundary? You potentially could clip the roads that cross the boundary of your clip feature, then append anything completely within the clip feature to the clipped output (Just a potential solution).